# AVAudioEngine - output format has 0 channels after changing device of auAudioUnit of the inputNode

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to change device of the `inputNode` of `AVAudioEngine`.

To do so, I'm calling `setDeviceID` on its `auAudioUnit`. Although this call doesn't fail, something wrong happens to the output busses.
When I ask for its format, it shows a 0Hz and 0 channels format. It makes the app crash when I try to connect the node to the mainMixerNode.

Can anyone explain what's wrong with this code?

```swift
avEngine = AVAudioEngine()

print(avEngine.inputNode.auAudioUnit.inputBusses[0].format)
// <AVAudioFormat 0x1404b06e0:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter>
print(avEngine.inputNode.auAudioUnit.outputBusses[0].format)
// <AVAudioFormat 0x1404b0a60:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, inter>
        

// Now, let's change a device from headphone's mic to built-in mic.
try! avEngine.inputNode.auAudioUnit.setDeviceID(inputDevice.deviceID)
        

print(avEngine.inputNode.auAudioUnit.inputBusses[0].format)
// <AVAudioFormat 0x1404add50:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter>
print(avEngine.inputNode.auAudioUnit.outputBusses[0].format)
// <AVAudioFormat 0x1404adff0:  0 ch,      0 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved>
// !!!

        
// Interestingly, 'inputNode' shows a different format than `auAudioUnit`
print(avEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
// <AVAudioFormat 0x1404af480:  1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>
print(avEngine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
// <AVAudioFormat 0x1404ade30:  1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>
```

**Edit:**
Further debugging revels another puzzling thing.

```
avEngine.inputNode.auAudioUnit == avEngine.outputNode.auAudioUnit // this is true ?!
```

`inputNode` and `outputNode` share the same `AUAudioUnit`. And its deviceID is by default set to the speakers. It's so confusing to me...why would inpudeNode's device be a speaker?

Comment: I have a similar problem when trying to connect a microphone node to the main mixer. I do have 2 channels, but the sampleRate is 0Hz. Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on both Simulator and device. My inputNode was reporting 2 channels, but 0 hz sample rate. Turns out I was starting the AudioEngine before attaching the nodes. Moved the start to the last step and it now works.

I have written quite a few AVAudioEngine Apps and can't believe I made this rookie mistake in my current App. However would be great if Apple could return an error from the connect() method stating the issue instead of just raising a generic fatal error.

Also I am using the AudioSession.setPreferredInput instead of the above setDevice. Using enableBuiltInMic method from here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones